# Retrieving data entry in a large matrix to perform summation in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a mXn matrix, where m= 1000 and n = 1000. Need to perform a complicated summation based on each data entry in the matrix.

For Ex: in the matrix, 'm' represents 'users' and 'n' represents 'items'. Summation will be performed only if there is a data entry corresponding to multiple users for same item.

```
     i1 i2 .......
---|---|--|---------------
u1 |1  |NA|
u2 |2  |2 |
u3 |NA |NA|
.
.
.
```

In the above matrix,

u1, u2, u3 ---- rows of a matrix
i1, i2, i3 ---- columns of the matrix

Here, u1 and u2 has data entry for i1 - Now I will need to retrieve the values to perform summation operation.

I thought it won't be efficient if I use two **for** loops to compare one user with another for each item column in a matrix of that size.

Please suggest me an efficient way to perform the above operation in R.

Below is the psuedo code that I will need to perform,

```
for(i=1 to length(column)){
  for(j=1; user1 -> row1){
    for(k=1; user2 -> row2){
       if(multiple_data_entries_exist_for_column){
         retrieve_data_entry_of_each_row
       else{
           go_to_next_column
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know a way that your code can be vectorized. In `R` this is quite an efficient approach.

```
user_matrix <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  i1 = c(1,2,NA),
  i2 = c(NA,2,NA) 
)
user_matrix
#   id i1 i2
# 1  1  1 NA
# 2  2  2  2
# 3  3 NA NA

tail(sapply(user_matrix, function(x) sum(x[!is.na(x)])),-1)
# i1 i2 
# 3  2
```

If you wanted to account for the fact that column 2 has only one entry, and you don't want to sum this column, you could do the following.

```
tail(sapply(user_matrix, 
  function(x) {
    y = !is.na(x)
    ifelse(sum(y)>1,sum(x[!is.na(x)]),NA)
}),-1)
# i1 i2 
 # 3 NA
```

Comment: nathanesau - Thanks! so, the efficient way is to use apply function family. I will try it out.

Comment: nathanesau - I will need to traverse through every row for each column and retrieve the value/ data corresponding to them to perform a fancy summation. The above solution will give me sums for each columns. The below is the pseudo code of what I need exactly.                                                         for(i=1 to length(column)){
  for(j=1; user1 -> row1){
    for(k=1; user2 -> row2){
       if(multiple_data_entries_exist_for_column){
         retrieve_data_entry_of_each_row
       else{
           go_to_next_column
           }
       }
    }
  }
}

Comment: nathanesau - sorry, I don't know why my psuedo code looks like that. I am not able to format it.